# Search Option In User Profile QA

Tags: feature-request, searching

I think that search option should be provided in questions and answers in the user profile, which is currently not available. Currently a user can see a list of own asked questions and given answers but he/she can't search particular one. It will help user to find a particular question or answer easily among all. It will helpful when one have to flag or suggest possible of duplicate or useful for suggesting someone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can search for posts by yourself by including the following term in a search:

```
user:me
```

See https://askubuntu.com/search for further search options.